# Spring bootで、SSLプロトコルに SSLv2 を指定すると起動に失敗する

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl

Spring boot の application.properties で `server.ssl.protocol` に SSLv2 を指定すると、以下のスタックトレースが表示されて起動に失敗します。

```
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SSLv2 SSLContext not available
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.getSSLContextInstance(SslContextFactory.java:1864)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.load(SslContextFactory.java:377)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory.doStart(SslContextFactory.java:244)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory.doStart(SslConnectionFactory.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:323)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:234)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.SslServerCustomizer$SslValidatingServerConnector.doStart(SslServerCustomizer.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer.start(JettyWebServer.java:161)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
```

使用している java バージョンは 11 です。

これは、以下のサイトで記載されている通り、Java 11 の JSSE が SSLv2 に対応していないからですか？

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html

また、java11 で SSLv2 を使用することはできるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

（そもそもセキュリティ的にSSLv2を使うのは無謀だと思いますがそれは置いておいて）JDK11にはSSLv3の実装は含まれていて細工をすれば有効化することができますが、SSLv2はオプションがないので使うことができません。